# vb (output is doubling in Richtextbox field)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, richtextbox

Using VB in Visual Studio 2012. I can't figure out how to clear whatever i need to clear.

See the code i'm using below:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    If RichTextBox1.Text > "" Then
        pingProc.CancelOutputRead()
        'Need Clearing code here
        RichTextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
    Me.Height = 522

    With pingProc.StartInfo
        .FileName = "cmd.exe"
        .Arguments = "/c C:\Tracert.bat"
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
    End With

    AddHandler pingProc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf HandleProcessOutput

    pingProc.Start()
    pingProc.BeginOutputReadLine()

End Sub

Private Sub HandleProcessOutput(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Me.Invoke(New DelegateAddText(AddressOf AddText), New Object() {e.Data})
End Sub

Delegate Sub DelegateAddText(ByVal Text As String)
Private Sub AddText(ByVal Text As String)
    RichTextBox1.Text &= Text & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Now when I run this code, it runs fine. but i will have to run it a second time or more. when i do i end up with double or more copies depending how many times I run this code.

First run:

```
Performing Trace Route to 198.224.169.244
Tracing route to 244.sub-198-224-169.myvzw.com [198.224.169.244]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
```

Second run:

```
Performing Trace Route to 198.224.169.244
Performing Trace Route to 198.224.169.244
Tracing route to 244.sub-198-224-169.myvzw.com [198.224.169.244]
Tracing route to 244.sub-198-224-169.myvzw.com [198.224.169.244]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
over a maximum of 30 hops:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might caused by `Addhandler` ... So, you can try this ..

```
Dim Handled As Boolean

If Not Handled Then 
  AddHandler pingProc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf HandleProcessOutput
  Handled = True
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help matzone. It seems that almost no matter where i put this in my code the text doubles up right away now. do you have a suggestion of where i should put it?

Comment: @Dam50fifty .. declare `handled` in class form and replace your addhandler statement with this if .. endif block ..